# Resampling in pandas (AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Day')

Tags: pandas, resampling

I'd like to resample dates in Pandas/Python.

I use this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
costs = pd.read_csv (r'/Users/erikvanderveen/Downloads/resampling.csv', skiprows=2, thousands=',').set_index('Day')
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
costs.head(5)
```

In the index column (Day) I see:

> 2020-08-01

When I use this code:

```
monthly_resampled_data = costs.Day.resample('M').mean()
```

This is the result:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Day'

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's because Pandas set the index on that column, so it's not a column in a dataframe, it's just an index.

Try to change this line

```
costs = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/erikvanderveen/Downloads/resampling.csv',
skiprows=2, thousands=',').set_index('Day')
```

to this line:

```
costs = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/erikvanderveen/Downloads/resampling.csv',
skiprows=2, thousands=',')
```

and then perform the rest. Please let me know if that worked.